# How to unload bpd program using bpftool?

Tags: ebpf, bpf

I've loaded an ebpf program using the `bpftool`, with the following command: `sudo bpftool prog load hello.bpf.o /sys/fs/bpf/my_ebpf_program`. How could I completely unload the program from the kernel? There doesn't seem to be an `unload` sub-command available.

Here is the output of the progs overview:

```
...
302: tracepoint  name tracepoint__sys  tag a04f5eef06a7f555  gpl
    loaded_at 2023-11-08T09:51:05+0000  uid 0
    xlated 16B  jited 16B  memlock 4096B
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BPF program is unloaded from the kernel once there are no more "references" to it. The reason you had to provide `bpftool` with a bpffs path is because it pinned your program to the FS at `/sys/fs/bpf/my_ebpf_program` so to unload your program you can delete this pin `rm -Rf /sys/fs/bpf/my_ebpf_program` which should unload the program (assuming no other processes are holding onto a reference)